# How to highlight a cell in excel using node js?

Tags: node.js

I have written node js script to form an excel file. My scenario is for some particular columns I need to apply conditional formatting for example column C values in my excel should follow color coding if its value is between 0-10 the green 11-50 it should show red else it should show yellow.

```
   var XLSX = require('xlsx')
   const sheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(excelJSON);
   XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb,sheet,"Book1");
```

where exceljson is the output of an sql query. Can anyone help me in doing this?